# Manifest merger failed how to solve?

Tags: android, android-manifest

After adding new library app showing error?
I am trying to add

```
compile 'com.github.badoualy:stepper-indicator:1.0.7'
```

and  after added this my app showing error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':sample:processShopifyDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from
> >     [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31       is
> >     also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2]
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-41 value=(26.0.0-beta2).    Suggestion: add
> >     'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

May be this is right way to solve this issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45258773/10010192

Comment: Did you try suggestion ?

Comment: I dont know where to add this line tools:replace="android:value"'

Comment: can you share AndroidManifest ?

Comment: updated please check it

Comment: after trying suggestion new error occured

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':sample:processShDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using multiple versions of Android support library. So Please choose one of version and use it for all libraries. Maybe you can try 25.4.0 for all. (You also need to change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 25.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

don't use 'compile' in build.gradle.

try to change

```
compile 'com.github.badoualy:stepper-indicator:1.0.7'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.github.badoualy:stepper-indicator:1.0.7'
```